# How can I evaluate: $\large \int \psi^{x^{\phi/\psi}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm having trouble evaluating the following integral: 
$$\large \int \psi^{x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}} dx$$

**Question**: How can I evaluate this integral? (Note: $\phi$ and $\psi$ are constants)

---

**Note**: *I know the solution (All hail WA), but I have no idea about the procedure of evaluation of this particularly neat integrand.*

[image]

Comment: I suppose $\phi$ and $\psi$ are constants?

Comment: Yes, indeed. @Travis

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @dustin One could simply use a different name for $\phi / \psi$ but the problem you mention otherwise seems largely unavoidable for this particular integral.

Comment: Right, sorry.... Done @dustin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start using $$\psi^{x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}}=\text{exp}\Big(x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}\log(\psi)\Big)$$ So $$ I=\int \psi^{x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}} dx=\int\text{exp}\Big(x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}\log(\psi)\Big)\,dx$$ Now change variable such that $x^{\frac{\phi}{\psi}}=y$ which leads to $$I=\frac{\psi  }{\phi }\int y^{\frac{\psi }{\phi }-1}e^{y \log(\psi)}\,dy$$ where you can recognize the incomplete gamma function after another change of variable $y \log(\psi)=-t$.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Comment: @ClaugeLeibovici , on a side note, could you please suggest a book can help me attain amateur mastery over integration? (i.e. all integrals not requiring contour integration)... I'm very young compared to you sir (You're still young as ever, in your capacity to do math :D ).. and would love to get advice from someone as experienced as you. To recap, I need a solid problem solving book for integration (Problems must be of high difficulty)

Comment: @Kugelblitz. Anybody is very young when compared to me ! I am just terrible with residues, contour integration and so on. Please notice than I am not a real mathematician (sometime here I feel as an alien not understanding anything). I just spent all my time around applied mathematics and numerical calculations. Why don't you post a question on this site ? Try to formulate it properly in order  people answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: Well sir, I'm only in tenth grade, hence I said so :) And yes, I posted about that (Not the exact query.. a related one) here in a related question, but it wasn't well received for some reason: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182087/how-to-use-table-of-integrals-by-gradshteyn-ryzhik-to-learn-integration

Comment: @Kugelblitz. Well, I saw your previous post and I must say that I did not like it because I do not think that you will **learn** from this book. Raymond Manzoni gave you some very good references. Ask a new question explaining what you are looking for. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

> *I have no idea about the procedure of evaluation of this particularly neat integrand.*

The whole idea is to [notice](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/639726/1) that the [Gaussian-like integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) $\mathcal G(n)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\big(-x^n\big)~dx$ possesses the remarkable property $~\mathcal G\bigg(\dfrac1n\bigg)=n!~,$ which can be shown by using the simple substitution $t=$ $\sqrt[\large^n]x~,~$ followed by immediately recognizing the consecrated expression of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in the new integral. Then the next step is to generalize the result for other bases than *e*, by employing the well-known logarithmic property $a=e^{\ln a}$, followed again by an appropriate substitution. Lastly, after disposing of integration limits, the latter is even further generalized with the help of [incomplete $\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).